# Mysql take a long time to load

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a website that mirror the hacked websites 
From the day of starting everything is cool till it's being bigger 
I have 2,197 records in MySQL DB  
Every time I want to load this page http://red-zone.org/archive/ 2,197 have to be shown. 
The cause that i'm using JavaScript for pagination and the JavaScript will work just after  loading all the records 
I don't like to use PHP for pagination 
Does there's any other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to use paging with big data is using Server-side processing with ajax/java script.

If you want a cool example you can look into datatables:
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Of you can make your own javascript, but i see your already using datatables try the server side processing it will resolve your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry but can explain more because i didn't understand anything :/

Comment: Now your loading all the data in your page, then allowing the javascript to page it, this is fine when you have small data.

But your problem is coming with big data, so the best is to load whats visible for the user, to achieve this you need to use the Ajax call and the paging in ajax its pretty very simple.

Comment: Your already using datatables as javascript, all you need to do create a server side page in php (its already in the example) and change the javascript configuration so you wont load the 2197 records you will load them partially. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html <-- use the server side script and add your table name with table options and thats it.

Comment: a Thank you very much Best Answer for you and please let us in contact if i just didn't understand something

Comment: Sure no problem, if you have multiple tables in your mysql you need a small trick if you have 1 table i dont think you will even have an issue... when your done tell me so i can check it on the site.

Comment: mm I have a problem a error show said `DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response.`

Comment: What's the json response in firebug?

Comment: it return null anyway i d a progress bar and i will keep using the first one

Comment: You need to check it with firebug or chrome debugger to see what's the error.

Comment: With the first one your database will have issues soon... give me your table name and columns and I can help you if u want.